# Memory leak after closing JPanels with large data JTables?

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jtable, jpanel

I have some JPanels attached to a JTabbedPane.
Each JPanel contains large data stored in JTable.

After displaying the Tabs in the JTabbedPane, the data is loaded and the memory allocated to the program jumps from 16Mb to 60Mb.

When closing any Tab (by means of `jTabbedPane.removeTabAt(selectedIdx)`), i notice that the allocated memory does not decrease.

I made a "Profiling" and "Heap Memory Dump". The result is: the JTable data is still in memory.

- Why does not `jTabbedPane.removeTabAt(selectedIdx)` free all the objects created within the panel added to the JTabbedPane object?
- How to fix it?

Comment: 1. `The result is: the JTable data is still in memory.` == this is correct result, 2 `What may be the problem here?` == everything is about `Each JPanel contains large data stored in JTable.` 3. `What may be the problem here?` == depends of what do you expect from each of Tab from JTabbedPane

Comment: I expect from the Tabs to display many panels. In the initComponents() method of each panel, some data are loaded. I want the memory to be released when the tabs are removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have references to JTable, for example you used addListener to some component and don't remove it. More particularly hard to say without code.